# Conservation of Energy-Stress in EM Field with charged matter

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I read in Wald's books on General Relativity that for a Energy-Stress tensor describing only the EM field with sources it isn't conserved. However the Energy-Stress Tensor of the EM field with charged matter is conserved.
Unfortunately I am not able to find any Energy-Stress Tensor for charged matter with an EM Field.
Could somebody please tell me how to write the Energy-Stress Tensor for such a task?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first we have to know why a Energy-Stress tensor is conserved. In the first case you're talking about a system where you have the evolution of an electromagnetic field with some sources. In that case we don't know the evolution of the sources so we don't have a closed system, so the Energy-Stress tensor is not conserved.

In the second case we have a closed system, because we are studying the evolution of our electromagnetic field and the evolution of our charges, so the Energy-Stress tensor is conserved.

If we want our tensor conserved we must have a closed system, without external fields or currents.

Here I let you a general equation for the Energy-Stress tensor that we obtain from the Lagrangian of the system, but you must know that the fact that the Energy tensor is conserved depends basically on the Lagrangian, not on the equation of the tensor.

$T_{\mu\nu}=2\frac{\partial L}{\partial \eta^{\mu\nu}}-\eta_{\mu\nu}L$

To have a Energy-Stress tensor conserved we have to know the QED Lagrangian and from it we obtain the tensor.